# OutputStream java.io.FileNotFoundException error

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, outputstream

i'm making a pdf converter. It will read a xml file and create a pdf, but I'm struggling with this file not found exception on my code.

If I have this, it works just fine:

```
OutputStream outFilePDF = new java.io.FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\almeida\\Desktop\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\FOLDER3\\FOLDER4\\FOLDER5\\Employees.pdf");
        outFilePDF = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(outFilePDF );
```

But like this, ...

```
String outFilePath = "C:\\Users\\almeida\\Desktop\\FOLDER1\\FOLDER2\\FOLDER3\\FOLDER4\\FOLDER5\\Employees.pdf";
OutputStream outFilePDF = new java.io.FileOutputStream(outFilePath);
        outFilePDF = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(outFilePDF );
```

I get this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Users\almeida\Desktop\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\FOLDER3\FOLDER4\FOLDER5\Employees.pdf" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Almeida

Comment: There might be an unprintable character in your string.  Try printing `outFilePath.length()`.

Comment: Hi. You're probably right becuase it has a length of 89. Do you have any tip? Thx

Comment: Since the first string is correct, copy it from there, and paste it into any code where you’re having trouble.  A longer term solution is to show non-printing characters in your IDE or text editor.